# How to enable a field of reactive forms?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am using reactive forms in my Angular 2+ app. I need to enable / to disable one field of my form dynamically.

For disable I'm using this code:
`this.cardForm.get('cvc').disable();`

It works good. But I don't know how to enable.
I'm trying:

- this.cardForm.get('cvc').removeAttribute('disabled');
  but I get ts eror

> Property 'removeAttribute' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'

- this.cardForm.get('cvc').enabled();

> Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'Boolean' has no compatible call signatures.

Comment: probably use without d this.cardForm.get('cvc').enable();

Comment: yes. you are right sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this.cardForm.get('cvc').enable()
```